# Restricting share options

Tags: java, android, shareactionprovider

Is there a way to restrict share options in an Android app? I have tried using the `ShareActionProvider` or just simply starting an intent using the `Intent.ACTION_SEND` intent option. Basically I want to be able to restrict sharing through email only or something of the sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like this, but instead of facebook look for a different name

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"this is a string");
shareIntent.setType("image/png");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri); //Share the image on Facebook
PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
                    for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
                        if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("facebook")) {
                            final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
                            final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(
                                        activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                                        activity.name);
                            shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                            shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                            shareIntent.setComponent(name);
                            startActivity(shareIntent);
                            break;
                                }
                            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the intent chooser as per your need like this -

```
List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
        if (!resInfo.isEmpty()){
            for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfo) {
                String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                Intent targetedShareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                targetedShareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject to be shared");
                if (StringUtils.equals(packageName, "com.facebook.katana")){
                    targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://link-to-be-shared.com");
                }else{
                    targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text message to shared");
                }

                targetedShareIntent.setPackage(packageName);
                targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent);


            }
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Select app to share");

            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));

            startActivity(chooserIntent);
        }
```

Hope this helps you.